# upstart - chain starting services

Tags: upstart

I have the following three services: `apache2`, `serviceFirst` and `serviceSecond`.

I want to run `serviceFirst` when `apache2` is up and running

I want to run `serviceSecond` when `serviceFirst` is up and running

file `/etc/init/serviceFirst.conf`:

```
# Info
description "UDP server"
author "Reggie Williams"

# Events
start on apache2
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

script 
     exec >/var/log/test.debug 2>&1 #so I can track when the service runs
     echo Gotcha...
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/server/udp/bin/serverrunner.php) = 'critical_error' ] && (stop; exit 1;)
end script
```

file `/etc/init/serviceSecond.conf`:

```
# Info
description "UDP client"
author "Reggie Williams"

# Events
start on (started serviceFirst)
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

script 
     exec >/var/log/test2.debug 2>&1 #so I can track when the service runs
     echo Gotcha2...
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/server/udp/bin/clientrunner.php) = 'critical_error' ] && (stop; exit 1;)
end script
```

So in these two services I run my scripts. Besides that I create one file per service and save them in `/var/log`.

However when I check timestamps of creation of these two files I can see that `test.debug` was created later than `test2.debug`.

So my question is: how is this possible and how to make sure that `serviceSecond` is really started after `serviceFirst` and `apache`?

Comment: yes, I had to edit apache upstart file and manually add "initctl emit apache2-started" command, because apache does not emit this event on ubuntu 14.04 with upstart. This is no longer an issue with systemd

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run service from `/etc/rc.local` with `&&`

edit `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add command

```
start service first && start service second
```

`&&` lets you do something based on whether the previous command
completed successfully

To be More precisely, `&&` will evaluate the second expression **iff the first expression returns 0**.